# "Could not find or load main class" command prompt

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked loads of times before, but I'm a rookie programmer and despite trying many of the solutions on this site I still can't fix this issue. I'll be really thankful if you can take the time to figure out what I've done wrong.

Operating system: Windows 8

Java version: 1.8.0 update 25

The command prompt I'm using is the one that comes with Windows. (I'm presuming there are other types so I'm just making it clearer.) The code's a really basic one.

```
package com.thefinshark.intro;

public class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Welcome.");
         }
    }
```

So, first I changed the directory to `C:\javawork`, where Welcome.java is saved. I set the path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`, then compiled the code. The compilation seemed fine, I found the Welcome.class file in the `C:\javawork` as well. The execution, however, kept returning "Could not find or load main class Welcome". I've tried `C:\javawork>java Welcome` and `C:\javawork>java com.thefinshark.intro.Welcome`, and loads of other variations. I've also changed the classpath to `C:\` and `C:\javawork` but it still dosen't work. Someone answering a similar question suggested adding dt.jar and tools.jar to the classpath but no dice.

It'll be great if someone could help, and I'll be happy to help pass on the information to the others who have problems like this as well. (As I'm typing this I'm looking at a whole long list of similar questions.)

Comment: Does the classpath contain `.`?  `java com.thefinshark.intro.Welcome` is the correct command, but the environment must be configured correctly.

Comment: @thefinshark Is there any reason for writing the code in a notepad and running it from command prompt? Try some IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse. IDE will help you, marking your mistakes and speeding up your learning process. To be honest I've never known why tutorials do tend to make rookies compile projects using command prompt. I feel this makes new programmers worry about the things like the one OP is facing instead of learning how to code.

Comment: "Someone answering a similar question suggested adding dt.jar and tools.jar to the classpath but no dice" - that person needs to be shot into outer space.

Comment: @spoko The guide I'm using utilises netbeans, but this notepad and command prompt thing is kinda in a pre-chapter, as an introduction I believe. I'm pretty stubborn, couldn't skip it until I figured out what was wrong even if it wasn't the main part.

Comment: @thefinshark sure. Actually I think your approach is pretty noble. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory structure must match the package name of your source file. So, if your class is in the package `com.thefinshark.intro`, then your source file must be in a directory `com\thefinshark\intro`.

So, for example, you should save your source file as `C:\javawork\com\thefinshark\intro\Welcome.java`, and then compile and run it from the directory `C:\javawork`:

```
C:\javawork> javac com\thefinshark\intro\Welcome.java
C:\javawork> java com.thefinshark.intro.Welcome
```

Note: The `javac` command expects a **filename** of the source file you are compiling (`com\thefinshark\intro\Welcome.java`), and the `java` command expects a **fully-qualified class name** (`com.thefinshark.intro.Welcome`).

See [Lesson: Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) for more details on how to work with packages.